# How to read the zip file contents in react application using jszip preferably

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zip, blob, jszip

I have a requirement to read the zip file contents , This is how the zip folder will look like Manifest.zip , The files in the Manifest.zip are outline.png, publish.png, manifest.json. I need to read the manifest.json(key value pairs) on the fly in a react application.

Basically requirement is when user clicks on "maifest" link a pop up needs to shown which show manifest.json contents in the UI react components.

I tried using JSZip library, and the code is as below

```
 var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.loadAsync("Manifest.zip")
      .then(function (zip) {
        console.log(zip.files);
        // Expected outline.png, publish.png, manifest.json
      });
```

I get the error as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Any code you have achieved at this moment?

Comment: I couldn't find any code related to this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) library. Seems stable and easy to use.

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

// reading archives
var zip = new AdmZip("./my_file.zip");
var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records

zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {

    console.log(zipEntry.toString()); // outputs zip entries information

});
```

Comment: Do we have type script version of it, I get this when I do Try `npm install @types/adm-zip` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'adm-zip';`

Comment: yes, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/adm-zip

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response, but adm-zip also uses fs internally in fileSystem.js and I get below error Failed to compile. I am using webpack for bundling and loading

./node_modules/adm-zip/util/fileSystem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '...\client\packages\app-configuration\node_modules\adm-zip\util'

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response, but adm-zip also uses fs internally in fileSystem.js and I get below error Failed to compile. I am using webpack for bundling and loading

./node_modules/adm-zip/util/fileSystem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '...\client\packages\app-configuration\node_modules\adm-zip\util' . I ended up getting the same when i use jszip library too as posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629554/when-trying-to-read-a-file-in-react-application-with-webpack-uncaught-typeerror

Comment: @DeepakKothari did you find a solution to read the zip file from the directory? if you did can you share me the concept you used

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the error is about, have you tried another zip file?

Anyway, here is my tsx code with reactjs hooks:

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<File[]>(undefined);
  const [fileInfo, setFileInfo] = useState<IFileInfo>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (files) {
      const f = files[0];
      const dateBefore = new Date();
      JSZip.loadAsync(f) // 1) read the Blob
      .then((zip) => {
          const contents = [];
          zip.forEach((relativePath, zipEntry) => {  // 2) print entries
            contents.push(zipEntry.name);
          });
          const loadTime = moment(new Date()).diff(moment(dateBefore));
          setFileInfo({
            loadTime,
            contents: contents.sort(),
            error: null
          });
      }, (e) => {
        const loadTime = moment(new Date()).diff(moment(dateBefore));
        setFileInfo({
          loadTime,
          contents: [],
          error: "Error reading " + f.name + ": " + e.message
        });
      });
    }
  }, [files]);

  // below some code that adds a file to files with drag and drop interface
```